# TaskDialog always on top in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, modal-dialog, taskdialog

Is there a way to make a TaskDialog always on top (ie, system modal)?

I've checked the TaskDialogConfig structure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787473(VS.85).aspx), but I'm not having any luck.

Anyone know how to do it or if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is helpful. But you can make the TaskDialog application modal if you supply a window handle to the `hwndParent` member of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You need to use TaskDialogIndirect function and set up a callback. In the callback you get window handle to the newly created TaskDialog. With that you can call SetWindowPos with necessary parameters.